# Create Mac terminal script with variable

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, sh

I'd like to create a script that executes several lines of code, but also ask the user a question to use as a variable.

For example, this is what I execute in terminal:

```
git add -A && git commit -m "Release 0.0.1."
git tag '0.0.1'
git push --tags
pod trunk push NAME.podspec
```

I'd like to make `0.0.1` and `NAME` as variables that I ask the user with questions to start the script off:

```
What is the name of this pod?
What version?
```

Then I'd like to merge these variables into the script above. I'm confused about what "dialect" to use (sh, bash, csh, JavaScript?, etc) and that extension I should save it as so I just have to double-click it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `bash` and `read`.  See [this article](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html).

Comment: Don't use read, it defeats the primary purpose of having a script: calling it programatically. It would be far better to have `usage: gitpod podname version` and aborting with help if there are invalid or insufficient arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "What is the name of this pod?" name
read -e -p "What version?" ver
git add -A && git commit -m "Release $ver."
git tag "$ver"
git push --tags
pod trunk push "$name".podspec
```

Give this script a suitable name (*script* or *script.sh* etc..), then assign proper permission:

```
chmod +x path/to/the/script
```

then run it from terminal:

```
path/to/the/script
```

---

You can make your script take the name and version as arguments too. A method to do that combining the above is:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="$1";ver="$2"
[[ $name == "" ]] && read -e -p "What is the name of this pod?" name
[[ $ver == "" ]] && read -e -p "What version?" ver
...
```

This has the advantage of taking arguments while working like the first one. You can now call the script with arguments:

```
path/to/the/script podname ver
```

and it won't ask for `name` and `ver`, instead it will take `podname` as name and `ver` as version from the arguments passed.

If the second argument is not passed, it will ask for ver.

If none of the arguments is passed, it will ask for both of them, just like the first code sample.